# Tight And Simple Upper Bound for $\sum_{k=1}^N \frac 1 {ak^n - b}$ for arbitrary $n > 0$ and large $N$

Tags: integration, upper-lower-bounds

I wonder how to find a tight and simple upper bound for

$$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac 1 {ak^n - b}$$

What I thought to use was an integration comparison test

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac 1 {ak^n - b} &\leq \int_{1}^{N} \frac 1 {a(x-1)^2 - b} dx \\
&= \left[ - \frac{\ln \left|\sqrt{\frac ab} (x-1) + 1\right| - \ln \left|\sqrt{\frac ab} (x-1) - 1\right|}{2\sqrt {ab}} \right]_{1}^N \\
&= - \frac{\ln \left|\sqrt{\frac ab} (N-1) + 1\right| - \ln \left|\sqrt{\frac ab} (N-1) - 1\right|}{2\sqrt {ab}}
\end{align}

If $n=2$. I find it hard to further simplify this expression for a polynomial form. Is there a better or simple way of developing the bound?

Comment: $x$ usualy denotes a real variable. It would be better to use, e.g., $k$ in place of $x$. You could also factor out $b\neq 0$ and call $a/b$ something (e.g., $c$).

Comment: It seems that your upper bound is negative which is a bit surprising. If $a>b$, you sum is positive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use $$\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac 1 {k^n - c} \leq \int_{1}^{N} \frac {dx} {(x-1)^n - c} =I $$ the integral is given in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I=\frac {N-1}c \,\,\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{n};1+\frac{1}{n};\frac{(N-1)^n}{c}\right)$$

But I think that you could compute the summations writing
$$k^n-c=\prod_{m=1}^n(k-r_m)$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac 1{k^n-c}=\sum_{m=1}^n \frac {A_m}{k-r_m}$$ and using generalized harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac 1 {k - r_m}=H_{N-r_m}-H_{-r_m}$$

Comment: Shouldn't you have $n$ in the integral somewhere? (And only one $dx$.)

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. It seems that this work only for integer $n$. What happens if it is more general like rational number. Is it still doable to develop the bound?